# Wrong value displayed

Tags: c#, class

I'm learning C#, I have this code :

```
namespace foo
{
    public class Personnes
    {
        string[] m_Noms;
        int m_NbElt;
        int m_Max;

        public Personnes(int Max)
        {
            m_Max = Max;
            m_NbElt = 0;
            m_Noms = new string[Max];
        }

        public int this[string Nom]
        {
            get { return Array.IndexOf(m_Noms, Nom); }
        }

        public string this[int i]
        {
            get { return m_Noms[i]; }
            set { m_Noms[i] = value;m_NbElt++; }
        }
    }
    class Prog
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Personnes Tableau = new Personnes(4);
            Tableau[0] = "Anna";
            Tableau[1] = "Ingrid";
            Tableau[2] = "Maria";
            Tableau[3] = "Ulrika";
            Console.WriteLine(Tableau[1]); 
            Console.WriteLine(Tableau["Maria"]);
            Console.WriteLine(Tableau[10]); 
            Console.WriteLine(Tableau["Toto"]); 


        }
    }
}
```

I've been told that  `Console.WriteLine(Tableau[10]);` should display null and the next line -1 but it doesn't, instead I have an error IndexOutOfRange, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is displaying IndexOutOfRangeException because you have set Tableau to have only 4 strings and any array retrieval beyond the index range[0 to 3] will result in this.

```
public string this[int i]
    {
        get { return m_Noms[i]; } <--  displays error if outside the range
        set { m_Noms[i] = value;m_NbElt++; }
    }
```

If you have to display null, then you need to add conditions in the indexer logic to check for the index value and if it is out of range return null

Comment: Ok I understand now, thank you! I've added condition on get if i > m_Max then return null and it works

Comment: @rn605435 :   To be on the safe side it might be worth making that (i > m_Max) || (I < 0).

Answer (score 4):

See you have initialized your array Tableau with just 4 `Personnes(4)`. And you are trying to get what is at `Tableau[10]`, so your are correctly getting [IndexOutOfRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f) exception. The index that you are seeking is out of the range specified.

Comment: OP has initialised the array to 4 not 5 using Personnes(4) - Tableau[4] would still generate an IndexOutOfRange exception.

Comment: _"m_Noms = new string[Max];"_ creates an array of length 4 (0-3) - it does not set the upper bound to 4. Try it & see.

Comment: @PaulF - Oh yes, you are right. Edited my ans. Thanks

Comment: You need to edit the last bit as well - all strings are allocated & none would return null.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been told that  Console.WriteLine(Tableau[10]); should display null and the next line -1 but it doesn't, instead I have an error IndexOutOfRange, why ?

Because whoever told you that was wrong. Accessing an array with an index that does not exist *should* throw an exception.

Comment: You were right thank you, but the explainations of the other answer allowed me to display the results I wanted